# Obtener el umbral utilizando binarización mediante método de Otsu

Tags: c++, opencv

El código sería el siguiente:

```
cv::Mat imagen(fil, col, CV_8UC1);

cv::Mat binarizada;

cv::threshold(imagen, binarizada, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

Me gustaría saber si es posible saber que umbral calcula el programa, ya que la función devuelve la imagen directamente binarizada.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con esto:

```
double value = cv::threshold(imagen, polarizada, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

Así, en teoría, deberías obtener el umbral utilizado únicamente por la opción `OTSU`

Comment: Sí, funciona perfectamente! Gracias!